# Azure Functions OpenApi File Upload POST Not Rendering

Tags: azure-functions, multipartform-data, swagger-ui, openapi

Following is the way I tried to configure a new Endpoint to my existing azure function to accept a file as the payload,

```
public class FormDataModel
{
    public byte[] FileUpload { get; set; }
}

[OpenApiOperation(operationId: "newconversionjobstream", tags: new[] { "New Conversion Job Stream" }, Summary = "Convert the given file from a source mimetype to a target mimetype", Description = "Convert the given file from a source mimetype to a target mimetype.", Visibility = OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]
[OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
[OpenApiParameter(name: "correlationid", In = ParameterLocation.Path, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Summary = "Id to track request, can be used to correlate processing between different micro services", Description = "Id to track request", Visibility = OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]
[OpenApiParameter(name: "jobid", In = ParameterLocation.Path, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Summary = "jobId of from the schedule conversion job", Description = "jobId", Visibility = OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]
[OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: "multipart/form-data", bodyType: typeof(FormDataModel), Required = true, Description = "Source File")]
[OpenApiResponseWithoutBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.Accepted, Summary = "The conversion job was accepted for processing. use the url on header to get the result", Description = "The conversion job was scheduled for processing. use the header url to get the job result")]
[Function("add-newconversion-job-stream")]
public Task<HttpResponseData> ScheduleNewConversionJobStream(
     [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "{correlationid}/new-conversion-job-stream/{jobid}")] HttpRequest req,
     string correlationid,
     string jobid,
     FunctionContext executionContext)
{
     var files = req.Form.Files;
```

When I try to go into the Swagger after running the function I'm getting the following error in the Swagger UI and Swagger Json

```
Sequence contains no elements

   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException()
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Visitors.ListObjectTypeVisitor.Visit(IAcceptor acceptor, KeyValuePair`2 type, NamingStrategy namingStrategy, Attribute[] attributes)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Visitors.OpenApiSchemaAcceptor.Accept(VisitorCollection collection, NamingStrategy namingStrategy)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Visitors.ObjectTypeVisitor.ProcessProperties(IOpenApiSchemaAcceptor instance, String schemaName, Dictionary`2 properties, NamingStrategy namingStrategy)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Visitors.ObjectTypeVisitor.Visit(IAcceptor acceptor, KeyValuePair`2 type, NamingStrategy namingStrategy, Attribute[] attributes)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Visitors.OpenApiSchemaAcceptor.Accept(VisitorCollection collection, NamingStrategy namingStrategy)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.DocumentHelper.GetOpenApiSchemas(List`1 elements, NamingStrategy namingStrategy, VisitorCollection collection)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi.Document.Build(Assembly assembly, OpenApiVersionType version)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi.Functions.OpenApiTriggerFunction.RenderSwaggerDocument(HttpRequestData req, String extension, FunctionContext ctx)
```

I've tried to find a way to configure the Azure Function to accept a fie, but above is the only way I found on configuring OpenAPI to upload a file as a payload,

I'm running .Net6 on Azure Functions Version 4

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sure, I have only posted the Image of the Rendered output on the Swagger UI, the actual Swagger Json error I have posted as text

Comment: You've posted a large image of a single line of text, which is the *Internal server error*. The rest isn't necessary, which means the image isn't necessary. Images should be used **only** when the problem cannot be shown in any other way, which clearly isn't the case with a single textual error message.

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1:*
I followed the steps
Create azure container
In the portal navigation pane on the left side of the screen, select **Storage accounts** and choose a storage account. If the navigation pane isn't visible, select the menu button to toggle its visibility.]
[image]
Go to save it~~strikethrough text~~

[image]

2. Select your Subscription , resource group and Storage account name and "**Review**"
   [image]

After click **on create**
[image]

Select the Go the resource
[image]

In Storage account you created go the **Container** and create a container

[image]
In visual studio 2020 Create a new Project
[image]
Select the azure Function and Click on the **Next**
[image]
Select the Project name and click on  **Next**
[image]
Select the Function as Http trigger with **OpenApi** and **Create**
[image]

```
    In **Function.cs** replace 
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Enums;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    
    namespace FunctionApp1
    {
        public class Function1
        {
            private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> log)
        {
            _logger = log;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "Run", tags: new[] { "name" })]
        [OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
        [OpenApiParameter(name: "name", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "The **Name** parameter")]
          [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/pdf", bodyType: typeof(File), Description = "The OK response")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
        {

            string Connection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
            string containerName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ContainerName");
            Stream myBlob = new MemoryStream();
            var file = req.Form.Files["File"];
            myBlob = file.OpenReadStream();
            var blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(Connection, containerName);
            var blob = blobClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
            await blob.UploadAsync(myBlob);
            return new OkObjectResult("file uploaded successfylly");
        }
    }
}

    In ***host.json***
    {
      "version": "2.0",
      "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
          "samplingSettings": {
            "isEnabled": true,
            "excludedTypes": "Request"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    In ***local.settings.json***
    {
      "IsEncrypted": false,
      "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "[Connection string]

(https://i.imgur.com/TtWgPYo.png)",
    "ContainerName": "[Your Container name](https://i.imgur.com/e7kb138.png)", // Container name
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

Run the application and copy the link of the **Post** method
and past in the **Postman**
[image]
Go the Body and select the file and click on send
[image]

Check the file in the container
[image]

Comment: The swagger file doesn't give a file upload button.